# Convert datetime date to bms month in column, not for index

Tags: python, dataframe, date, datetime

I am wanting to change my date column from the format directly below to have it looking like the start of a business month. I don't want to make it into an index, I would like ensure that it stays as a column. Any help would be awesome!

```
date        id
2000-11-18   A
2000-11-18   B
2000-11-18   C
2000-12-18   A
2000-12-18   B
2001-1-18    C
2001-1-18    A
```

**Start of business month desired**

```
date        id
2000-11-1    A
2000-11-1    B
2000-11-1    C 
2000-12-2    A
2000-12-2    B
2001-1-2     C
2001-1-2     A
```

Comment: how do you define `start of a business month`? Apart from obvious problems defining that, why last two entries yield different result?

Comment: Also, please post what have you tried so far.

Comment: @buran 

I define start of business month as 'BMS' when you resample. I can do the following by making the date an index and resampling. But for what I want to do, this method is not appropriate. A way without converting to index would be perfect!

What I have done:

df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']))
df.resample('BMS').first()

Comment: How can you have 2001-1-2 for a BMS when 2001-01-01 is a Monday? Same question for 2000-12-01 which a a Friday?

Comment: By "defining" I mean what is start of business month? First day of month, First working day of the month or something else? Which holidays/non-working days do you count - different regions/countries have different holidays,  etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DateOffset` can be used to rollback a Timestamp to the appropriate business frequency.

```
df['date'] -= pd.offsets.BMonthBegin()
```

It gives:

```
        date id
0 2000-11-01  A
1 2000-11-01  B
2 2000-11-01  C
3 2000-12-01  A
4 2000-12-01  B
5 2001-01-01  C
6 2001-01-01  A
```

which is consistent with the code that you gave in comment. With the original dataframe, I can do:

```
>>> df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date'])).resample('BMS').first()
                 date id
date                    
2000-11-01 2000-11-18  A
2000-12-01 2000-12-18  A
2001-01-01 2001-01-18  C
```